# Margin left- px

Tags: html, css, margin

Can I use any tag that will allow me to place a line `<hr />` on a specific left margin size

Comment: Please revise your question to describe what you are trying to do a bit clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
<hr style="margin-left:10px;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a div and add a border to that div. It's more flexible than the

---

tag. This would be a example for a solid line with a margin of 5 px to the top and bottom and 10px to the left and right:

```
<div style="border-top:1px solid #000;margin:5px 10px;"></div>
```

I haven't tested it but that should work fine :)

edit: i tested it with firebug and edited the code above.

Comment: Support this answer - there is no way to make the HR behaviour identical in all browsers (with standards hacks like *html), so you should prefer DIV with border in all cases. For DIV case for IE6-IE7 browsers you also may need to specify font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px;